# How to use add assembly reference MSXML2 in C#?

Tags: c#, msxml

Following references I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using MSXML2;
```

Not find MSXML2 reference. 
I have already installed msxml6_x64.msi. 
And using Visual Studio 2013 with Windows 8 64 bit.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need that library?  Anything it can do can be done natively

Comment: multiple versions of msxml all use this namespace... check the clsid for the exact version expected by the program. but if u call msxml a lot of times, native-managed transition gonna slowdown your performance. better use syste,.xml instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to `C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll`